# Reissue summons if service fails?

Tags: civil-procedure, civil, service

If a Plaintiff fails to serve a Defendant at the address listed in the Summons, does the Summons have to be reissued with the accurate address before service can take place or can service of process be made at the new address without going back to the court again?

Answer (score 1):

A summons is served on the person. If the person has moved, the server will take it to the new address.

Some states allow you to send notice to the person's last known address.

Comment: Correct. It is worth noting that a summons sometimes has an expiration date on its face. When that is true and the summons is not served before the expiration date, a new substitute document, called an "alias summons" must be obtained. But, an alias summons is not required for a mere change of address.